# Riemann zeta function form for Dirichlet series of lcm$[m,n]^{-s}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Define $$f(k) = |\{(m, n) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : [m,n] = k\}|$$ and $$F(s) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{f(i)}{i^s}$$ where $s= \sigma + it \in \mathbb{C}.$
Write $F$ in Reimann zeta function form and determine its half-plane of absolute convergence.

I would like to study this problem. First, I notice that $$F(s) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{f(i)}{i^s} =\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{[m, n]^{s}} = \sum_{m>1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty [m, n]^{-s} + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^s} = \sum_{m>1, n= 1,2,3...} [m, n]^{-s} + \zeta(s). $$ For $m = 2$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{[m, n]^s} = \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{6^s} + ... = \frac{1}{2^s} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^s} + \sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^s} = 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^s} - \frac{1}{4}.$$
Not sure what is the Riemann zeta form of that. I also think that this is not a good idea to acheive the formula (if it has pattern, it might suggest the formula.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We first claim the following:

> **Lemma.** For any $n\in\mathbf Z_+$ it holds that
>   $$f(n)=d(n^2),$$
>   where $d(\cdot)$ is the **divisor function**.

*Proof*. We prove it by induction on the number of factors of $k$. If $k$ is a power of a prime then the result is plainly true, so suppose that it holds when $k$ has $N$ distinct prime factors, and we will show that

$$f(k\cdot p^\gamma)=f(k)f(p^\gamma)$$

for any prime $p$ that does not divide $k$. Indeed, a pair $(a,b)$ satisfies that $[a,b]=kp^\gamma$ iff either $p^\gamma|a$, $p^j|b$ ($j=0,\dots,\gamma$) and $[a/p^\gamma,b/p^j]=k$ or $p^j|a$ ($j=0,\dots,\gamma-1$), $p^\gamma|b$ and $[a/p^j,b/p^\gamma]=k$. Since there are $f(k)\cdot (\gamma+1)$ possibilities in the former case, and $f(k)\cdot \gamma$ in the latter, we have that the number of possible pairs is

$$f(k)[\gamma+1+\gamma]=f(k)(2\gamma+1)=d(k^2)d(p^{2\gamma})=d(k^2p^{2\gamma})=f(kp^\gamma).$$

This proves the lemma. $\blacksquare$

From the lemma, we see then that

$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{f(n)}{n^s}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{d(n^2)}{n^s}.$$

Since $d(n^2)$ is a multiplicative function, we know that

$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{d(n^2)}{n^s}=
\prod_{p}\left\{1+\frac{d(p^2)}{p^s}+\frac{d(p^4)}{p^{2s}}+\dots\right\}
$$

where the product is extended to all the primes. This is,

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{d(n^2)}{n^s}
&=\prod_{p}\left\{1+\frac{3}{p^s}+\frac{5}{p^{2s}}+\dots\right\}\\
&=\prod_p\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{2l+1}{p^{sl}}\\
&=\prod_p
\frac{p^s \left(p^s+1\right)}{\left(p^s-1\right)^2}\\
&=\prod_p\frac1{1-p^s}\prod_p(1+p^{-s})\prod_p\frac1{1-p^{-s}}\\
&=\zeta(s)\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}\zeta(s)\\
&=\frac{\zeta(s)^3}{\zeta(2s)}.
\end{align}$$

Hence

$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{f(n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s)^3}{\zeta(2s)},\qquad\text{whenever }\Re(s)>1.$$

Comment: I would start with : if $gcd(k,k') = 1$ and $lcm(m,n) = k,  lcm(m',n') = k'$ then $lcm(mm',nn') = kk'$ and conversely, if $lcm(a,b) = kk'$ then $a = mm',b = nn', lcm(m,n)=k,lcm(m',n')=k'$, thus $f(k)$ is multiplicative.

Comment: @iqcd I try to convince myself about your Lemma, but I am not sure if it is correct. If I do not calculate anything wrong, $$f(6) = |\{(1,6), (2,6), (3,6), (6,6), (6,1), (6,2), (6,3)\}| = 7$$ but $$d(36) = d(2^2)d(3^2) = 9 ?$$

Comment: Oh, okay. It is just silly that I forget $(2, 3)$ and $(3, 2)$. Okay, so it seems that your Lemma is perfectly fine. Could you tell me the intuition ? I mean how can you recognize that this two functions are the same. I really have no idea that the number of ordered pairs for $[m, n]$ is exactly the number of positve divisor of a square.

Comment: @user1952009 Definitively a quicker and much better solution. I don't know why I didn't start trying that out first

Comment: @BothHtob I thought "If this function is multiplicative, then it is easy". After proving it, I noticed that $f(p^\gamma)=2\gamma+1$ for each prime, and recalled that $d(p^\gamma)=\gamma+1$, so the identification became evident.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Since $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty d(k^2)/k^2 \geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2/k$$ which is divergent. So half-plane of convergent is a subset of $\mathbb{R}_{>2},$ but the formula in term of Riemann zeta function is valid for any $Rs(s) > 1$. Does this make sense ? I feel like it contradicts each other.